# MVC 5 ajax not working in default project

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-ajax

i have created a default MVC 5 project. i used Entity Framework 6. I created a simple person class with Id and Name as a model. Then i generated CRUD operation for it using MVC 5 template after running the  code first migration. i implemented a delete functionality everything is working fine.

but when i copied the same code other MVC project. but this project contains some additional css and js. whenever i click on delete or any other operation page is posting back. i want to know why it is happening and why default project has every thing enabled with Ajax.
what i am missing in this project

Answer (score 0):

To enable ajax helpers:

```
Install-Package microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax
```